# Simultaneous <forms>- and <sessionState> timeout

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an asp.net webforms application. My root web config has the following entries:

```
<forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="60" path="/"/>
```

...

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" 
stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1" cookieless="false" timeout="60"/>
```

I want to know what happens when the user is idle for 61 minutes. Will a httprequest of type 401 occur regardless if the `<forms>` or `<sessionState>` triggers a redirect?

My goal is to handle the XHR status in a jQuery $.ajax error callback and check if the user should be  redirected to the loginpage or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sessionState timeout doesn't automatically trigger a redirect, your application just won't find the session objects that it may be looking for.  Does your code check the session and fire off a redirect?  If so, the forms timeout (and subsequent redirect to Login.aspx page) will be experienced by the user prior to your session timeout handling (which wouldn't execute).